# When exactly does a dynamic array get garbage collected?

Tags: delphi

Dynamic arrays are reference counted, and so the memory is freed automatically by the compiler. My question is, when exactly does this automatic freeing occur? Does it happen *immediately*, or at the end of the containing procedure?

Here is a concrete example

```
procedure DoStuff;
var data:TBytes;
begin
  data:=GetData; // lets say data now contains 1 Gig of data.
  DoStuffWithData(data);
  // I now want to free up this 1Gig of memory before continuing.
  // Is this call needed, or would the memory be freed in the next line anyway?
  Finalize(data); 

  data:=GetMoreData; // The first array now has no remaining references
  DoStuffWithData(data);
end
```

Is the call to Finalize() redundant?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The call to `Finalize` isn't quite redundant. It's true that the dynamic array's reference count will be decremented on the next line (therefore destroying the array, probably), but that will only happen *after* the new dynamic array is allocated. Just before the return of `GetMoreData`, but before the assignment takes place, there will be *two* dynamic arrays in memory. If you destroy the first one manually in advance, then you'll only have one array in memory at a time.

The *second* array that you store in `data` will get destroyed as `DoStuff` returns (assuming `DoStuffWithData` doesn't store a copy of the dynamic-array reference elsewhere, increasing its reference count).

Comment: To clarify, in this case, assignment to `data` will be when you assign/`SetLength` `Result` in `GetMoreData`. Dynamic types that are returned from functions works like this: `GetMoreData(var Result: TBytes);`

Answer (score 1):

> When exactly does this automatic freeing occur? Does it happen immediately, or at the end of the containing procedure?

Dynamic memory associated with managed types (dynamic arrays fall into this class) is freed when the reference count is set to 0. This can happen at the following points:

1. The reference variable is assigned a new value. A call to Finalize can be thought of as the special case where the new values is nil.
2. The reference variable goes out of scope. For example:

   - The exit of a function is reached; local variables go out of scope.
   - An object is destroyed and its members go out of scope.
   - A pointer to a record is destroyed with the Dispose function; all fields of the record go out of scope.
   - A unit is finalized and all global variables defined in the unit are finalized.

Note that the various cases above only result in memory being freed when the reference that is being finalized or is leaving scope is the last remaining reference. In other words, when the reference count is 1.

In your specific example, assuming the Finalize is removed, you are creating a new dynamic array and assigning it to a variable that already holds a dynamic array. This then falls into the class described by item 1 in the list above. So in that sense the call to Finalize is superfluous.

Rob has explained the order in which the allocation and deallocation happens which is a good point. To the best of my knowledge that is an implementation detail that is not explicitly documented. However, I'd be astounded if that detail was ever changed.